# ffmpeg video converting issue

Tags: php, video-processing, video-conversion

I am just trying to upload and converting video using ffmpeg library its working on my local machine its working fine but as upload it on my server it didn't work.
Can any one  tell me where is fault here is my code

```
$ffmpeg = "/home/public_html/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg"; 
$video = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = "200x100"; 
$imageFile = date("Y-m-d").".jpg";
$getFromSecond = 120;

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
$cmd_convert = "$ffmpeg -i $video output.flv &";

if(!shell_exec($cmd)) {     echo "Thumbnails Crated"; } else {  echo
"Thumbnails Not Crated"; }
```

This working fine on my local machine video is converting and thumbnails are being get  but not working on my server

Thanks

Comment: `shell_exec` function must be disabled in your server.. ask your webmaster to enable it....

Comment: Thanks for help Nishant  let me ask them

Comment: check shell_exec() is not present in disable_functions in php.ini

Comment: This function is not disabled in the 'php.ini' file. webmaster reply but still it is not working